# How do I know whether android:textColor has int or ColorStateList value

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view, textcolor

In a custom view group, I have a TextView as a child. I want to set this TextView's textColor based on android:textColor value. So in res/values/styles.xml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="CustomViewGroupTextView">
    <attr name="android:textColor" />
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

And in CustomViewGroup's constructor, I have this:

```
private TextView mTextView;    

public CustomViewGroup(Context context) {
  super(context);
  initTextView(context, attrs);
}

public CustomViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
  initTextView(context, attrs);
}

public CustomViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
  super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  initTextView(context, attrs);
}

private void initTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  mTextView = new TextView(
  TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomViewGroupTextView);

  // Set text color
  ColorStateList textColor = ta.getColorStateList(R.styleable.MinutiaeTextView_android_textColor);
  if (textColor != null) {
    mTextView.setTextColor(textColor);
  }
}
```

My question is: how do I properly do mTextView.setTextColor? Anyone can put a whole color state list or a single color value in android:textColor. Or will I get a ColorStateList with all the same color if someone put a single color in android:textColor?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#getColorStateList%28int%29):

> The value may be either a single solid color or a reference to a color or complex ColorStateList description

So, if the user set the color to a single value, you will get a single value, else you will get a reference to a `ColorStateList`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to change the color of a TextView:

```
mTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED); (RED, WHITE, BLACK....)

mTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(200,0,0));

mTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourcolor));

mTextView.setTextColor(0xAARRGGBB);
```

EDIT:
In your layout xml file use this property in the specific TextView:

```
android:textColor="Here"
```

Where you read Here you can write:

```
android:color/white (black, red...)

color/yourcolorname

#738184
```

Etc...

Comment: Yes I know. The question is how do I know whether to do mTextView.setTextColor(ColorStateList) or mTextView.setTextColor(int)? All I only know is that someone set the android:textColor, and they can set a reference to a style, or a single color.